# Delete element from Array based on fibonacci sequence

Tags: c, arrays, list, fibonacci

I have to write the function C that receives a linked list with L pointers of values ​​of type int, e
returns among the formal parameters a V array obtained in the following way:

- Initially, the function removes from the list L the elements whose position corresponds to a Fibonacci sequence number (assume that the first element of the list has position 1 and that the first two values ​​of the Fibonacci sequence are F0 = 1, F1 = 2, with the generic element of the sequence given by Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2);
- Elements removed from L are inserted into the V array so that the last element removed from L is the overhead element of V (the array V must be allocated internally to the function.) list L).

Each element of the L list has the following form:

```
struct list {
   int value;
int pos; // posizione occupata inizialmente nella lista struct list * 
next_ptr;
};
```

where the position occupied by the element in the list does not change during the execution.
I wrote the following code and would like you to review it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
typedef unsigned short int Boolean;
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
#include "header.h"
struct list{
int value;
int pos;
struct list * next_ptr;
};

Boolean function (struct list **L, int** V, int *length){
int i, j, size;
int * F;
struct list * positionPtr=*L;
struct list ** ptrptr=L;
struct list *tmp;
while (positionPtr!=NULL && positionPtr->next_ptr!=NULL)
    positionPtr=positionPtr->next_ptr;
if (positionPtr!=NULL) size=positionPtr->pos;
else return FALSE;
*V=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size));
F=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size));
if (*V==NULL || F==NULL) return FALSE;
F[0]=1;
F[1]=2;
for (i=2;i<size && F[i-1]<size;i++)
    F[i]=F[i-1]+F[i-2];
i=0;
j=size-1;
while (*ptrptr!=NULL){
    if ((*ptrptr)->pos==F[i]) {
        (*V)[j] = (*ptrptr)->value;
        tmp = *ptrptr;
        *ptrptr = (*ptrptr)->next_ptr;
        free(tmp);
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    else
        ptrptr=&((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);
}
for (i=j+1;i<size;i++)
    (*V)[i-j-1]=(*V)[i];
*length=size-j-1;
return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: You want a review of code which basically does what it supposed to do? Or is there a specific misbehaviour you cannot fix and want help with?

Comment: it does not work and I do not understand why

Comment: Post the inputs used, outputs seen and expected  that "does not work" to add clarity to the post.

Comment: There’s more code there than in an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: regarding: `struct list {
   int value;
int pos; // posizione occupata inizialmente nella lista struct list * 
next_ptr;
};`  That will not compile/work.  Perhaps you meant: `struct list {
   int value;
int pos; // posizione occupata inizialmente nella lista struct list * 
struct list *next_ptr;
};`

Comment: how do you expect us to help you when you have the statement: `#include "header.h"`  but have not supplied the contents of `header.h`?

Comment: regarding: `typedef unsigned short int Boolean;
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1`  this is a very bad idea.  Much better to include the header file: `stdbool.h`  and use the definitions within that file

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}', Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.

Comment: Note: the header file `header.h`  contains nothing that is needed for the posted code, so why is it being included?

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ) 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  3) the parameter is type `size_t`, so should not be passing `int` variables

Comment: variable names and parameter names should indicate `content` or `usage`.  Names like `L` and `V` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert appropriate horizontal spacing: after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, and around C operators

Comment: regarding: `if (*V==NULL || F==NULL) return FALSE;`  each of these checks should be immediately after the call to `malloc()` that set the variable.  When the contents is `NULL`, should output a error message to `stderr`, using `perror()`, so both the error message AND the reason the system thinks the error occurred are output.

Comment: regarding: `(*V)[i-j-1]=(*V)[i];`   What are you expecting this to perform?   Do you realize that `*V` is the contents of the array `V[]`, first entry. an `int`, not some pointer

Comment: regarding: `ptrptr = &((*ptrptr)->next_ptr);`  is suspect you actually want the contents of the pointer, not the address of the pointer